# React Hooks Re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component that has two pieces of state:

```
 let [data, setData] = useState([]);
 let [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

I also have a simple useEffect hook that calls a function that returns a promise:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    someFunctionThatReturnsAPromise().then({
            console.log("Before setData");
            setData(dataFromFetch);
            console.log("After setData");
            console.log("Before setLoading");
            setLoading(true);
            console.log("After setLoading");
        }
        );
},[]);




return (
        <div>
            console.log("Hey i rendered");
        </div>
    );
```

Seeing as i have an empty dependency array ( [] inside useEffect ), this useEffect will only run once. My question is:

Seeing as setData causes the component to re-render, shouldn't as soon as the code reaches `setData(dataFromFetch);`, shouldn't the execution stop? In my console log, the this is what gets printed:

```
Hey i rendered
Before setData
Hey i rendered
After setData
Before setLoading
Hey i rendered
After setLoading
```

I expected something like:

```
Hey i rendered
Before setData
Hey i rendered
```

Why does the execution continue even after the component re-renders? Where can i go to read up on something like this?

Comment: The `console.log()`s in `useEffect` are independent from the `console.log` that you have in the render method. They are going to run regardless of the amount of renders. So I'm not sure why you wouldn't expect those to run...

Comment: @silencedogood isn't there only one thread in this application? When the thread hits the setData(), shouldnt it go straight to rendering the component again ( start executing the return )? Right now, what im seeing is, Main thread prints the console.log() in return, then goes inside the then() when it gets resolved, then calls setData(), then goes to rerender the component again, so it calls the console.log() in return again, THEN IT GOES BACK to where it left off, continiuing after setData, etc etc.

Comment: you need to return a clean up function: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1

Comment: The component isn't unmounted so it will still continue to log.

Comment: @Viet i dont get how a cleanup function would help. I'm just interested in how the main thread navigates through the code when there is a re-render.

Comment: @JosephD. so everytime a component re-renders, till the previous component unmounts, i will have several components being run at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is added to the javascript event stack and is asynchronous by nature and useEffect is being executed fully via the javascript call stack regardless of other async functions added to the end of the stack (such as console.logs and setStates)

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Heres an article on the event queue/javascript lifecycle that may explain better:
https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-event-loop/

Comment: But setState gets called before the useEffect finishes. The Hey i rendered logs are proof of that.

Comment: i believe this is an effect of the javascript lifecycle/ event loop as well since console logs are async same as setState. (i updated to the correct article as i copied the wrong link from my notes)