# React, React Hooks, Diffrent console.log print order inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-lifecycle

I am getting two diffrent orders of console.log prints based on wheater i am using a promise or not.

The state:

```
let [data,setData] = useState(1);
```

When using promise:

```
let asyncFunk = async () => {
      return "Asd";
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        asyncFunk().then((result) => {
            console.log("BEFOR SET DATA " +data);
            setData(prev => prev +1 );
            console.log("AFTER SET DATA " +data);
        });
    },[]);

    return (
       <div>
            {console.log("Data in return " + data)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

The console.log print order is:

```
Data in return 1
BEFOR SET DATA 1
Data in return 2
AFTER SET DATA 1
```

So when the setData() is hit, the component re-renders, and the console.log from the return gets called BEFORE the console.log after the setData().

When i remove the async function:

```
 useEffect(() => {
            console.log("BEFOR SET DATA " +data);
            setData(prev => prev +1 );
            console.log("AFTER SET DATA " +data);
    },[]);
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log("Data in return " + data)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

The console.log print order is:

```
Data in return 1
BEFOR SET DATA 1
AFTER SET DATA 1
Data in return 2
```

When the async function is removed, the useEffect finishes first, and also prints the old state value as well, then the console.log from the return gets printed.

**Any idea whats going on here and why this is the order the prints are happening?**

Comment: Just a small tip, you could have called `console.log` before the `return`. No need for calling it inside the return.

Comment: Hopefully someone can explain it better than I did in your last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58544214/react-hooks-re-renders), however this has to do with the javascript event loop lifecycle and call stack [Javascript event loop](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-event-loop/) "There's a big difference between Promises (and Async/await, which is built on promises) and plain old asynchronous functions through setTimeout() or other platform APIs."

Comment: Im kinda having trouble fitting in RE-RENDERS inside the javascript event loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does React batch state update functions when using hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048495/does-react-batch-state-update-functions-when-using-hooks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a implementation of React.

Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53048903/9119186) where it says.

> TL;DR – if the state changes are triggered asynchronously (e.g. wrapped in a promise), they will not be batched; if they are triggered directly, they will be batched.

And if you take a look at the [comment of Dan Abramov](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10231#issuecomment-316644950) it says

> In current release, they will be batched together if you are inside a React event handler.
>   ...
>   With current version, several setStates outside of event handlers (e.g. in network responses) will not be batched. So you would get two re-renders in that case.
>   ...

So what is happening where is an expected result.